# What are the prerequisites for Terence Tao's Additive Combinatorics book?

Tags: combinatorics

The title says it all, i want to know what are the mathematical prerequisites to work through Tao's additive combinatorics book.

Comment: Go to Libgen and find out yourself ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The authors Terence Tao and Van H. Vu recommend in the Prologue of *[Additive Combinatorics](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/additive-combinatorics/D408BA34B567974CC8FB0CEC2A49A807)* some familiarity with
>
> - elementary combinatorics
> - harmonic analysis
> - convex geometry
> - incidence geometry
> - graph theory
> - probability
> - algebraic geometry and
> - ergodic theory.
>
> They also write after providing us with the list above:
>
> - ... this wealth of perspectives makes additive combinatorics a rich, fascinating, and multi-faceted subject.
> - ... The main purpose of this book is to gather all these diverse tools in one location, present them in a self-contained and introductory manner, and illustrate their application to problems in additive combinatorics.

You might also find the

- *[AMS review](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2009-46-03/S0273-0979-09-01231-2/S0273-0979-09-01231-2.pdf)* by Ben Green and the
- *[Review of Additive Combinatorics](https://www.cs.umd.edu/%7Egasarch/bookrev/45-1.pdf)* (see p. 16 - 18) by Raghunath Tewari

helpful and informative.